# Get post data using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to pull content from Wordpress posts AJAX.

I have included my efforts so far below.

Loaded scripts.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.ajax a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
      data: {'action' : 'ajax_request', 'id': id},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });     

    return false;

  });

});
```

Here I set up my action. *How to encode post data as JSON and return?*

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');

function ajax_handle_request(){
}
```

Comment: When are you wanting to pull informations from the posts, on or after posting? Also what information do you want to pull?

Comment: FYI, there *is* a [WordPress-specific Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com), although questions like this *are* welcome here as well.

Comment: Also, if your goal is to learn about AJAX and JSON in general, this WordPress example is probably not the best starting point, as WordPress doesn't really have an API for this sort of thing (I don't think), and certainly not a standard-looking one that returns a nice JSON result. I use AJAX extensively, but honestly have always struggled trying to do what you want with WordPress.

Comment: @iRector I want to pull post information on anchor click. I have added a data attribute to anchors that include the the id of the post. I want to include the get_post($post_id) variable which includes all the information about the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

I'm seeing activity on this post, and it's very old.

Please use the WP REST API instead:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

---

I was able to figure this out by setting global $post variable.

Then by encoding the $response.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');

function ajax_handle_request(){

    $postID = $_POST['id'];
    if (isset($_POST['id'])){
        $post_id = $_POST['id'];
    }else{
        $post_id = "";
    }

    global $post;
    $post = get_post($postID);

    $response = array( 
        'sucess' => true, 
        'post' => $post,
        'id' => $postID , 
    );

    // generate the response
    print json_encode($response);

    // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
    exit;
}
```

Using jQuery to retrieve the data and output.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.ajax a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
      data: {'action' : 'ajax_request', 'id': id},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data['post']);
      }
    });     

    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions [`wp_send_json_success`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success) and [`wp_send_json_error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_error) to return the Ajax request result.

Both of them use [`wp_send_json`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/functions.php#L2321), which takes care of the header, JSON encoding and echoing, and to die.

Also, you should send a nonce when localizing the script:

```
array(
    'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( "my_long_unique_string_name" ),
)
```

And check it within `wp_ajax_*` action callback:

```
check_ajax_referer( 'my_long_unique_string_name', 'nonce' );
```

<sub>*Example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106436/12615*</sub>

Comment: How would I call these functions given my answer above? 
Does my solution suggest any call to the ajax_request action is technically a success then?

Comment: @hyperdrive, if post ID is not set, I'd return an error. See the example I linked...