# WordPress AJAX call refuses to return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to return some meta data once a select field changes.  However, I've done several iterations of the code below, and it works fine if I simply echo it from a php script, but when I try to return it as a response, it fails. I know that it's definitely running the function because if I simply tell it to 'echo 'xxxx', it works. Below is the code I'm attempting to implement.  I'm completely stumped and hope I'm simply overlooking something...

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'get_criteria_javascript');

function get_criteria_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(jQuery('select#pages').length > 0) {
        jQuery('select#pages').live('change', function() {
            var selected = jQuery(this).val();
            var data = { action: 'get_criteria', post_id: selected };

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: 'admin-ajax.php',
                data: {action: 'get_criteria', post_id : selected },
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_criteria', 'get_criteria_callback');

// if I use echo get_criteria_callback(627); here, it returns the expected results... 

function get_criteria_callback($post_id) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'criteria');
    $content = implode(', ', $meta[0]); 
/* This is one version. Although I can echo it fine, if I return this as a response, it tells me my implode is using invalid arguments */

    echo $content;
    die();
 }
```

Comment: Pretty sure jquery doesn't trigger document.ready again after an ajax request. It's only triggered on page load.

Comment: Thanks, I did try to omit that in a previous iteration, but the result was the same.  Works if I echo it, doesn't work as a response.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18305104/1287812)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax call the url parameter should not be hardcoded, use `ajaxurl` instead. an ajax call is a new http request. So the data you send is passed through POST method.

```
function get_get_criteria_callback(){
  $post_id = isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) ? $_POST['post_id'] : false;

  if( $post_id ){
    $meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'criteria');
    $content = implode( ', ', $meta[0] );
  }

  echo $content;

  die();

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I originally had ajaxurl in there, but it made no difference.  I keep thinking I'm missing something obvious, but can't figure it out...

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't get what you meant the first time around, but yes, using $_POST did work! So thanks again!

Comment: @JenniferFletcher, you're welcome. if my English was better, I would have solved this problem immediately : )